# Flash stripping params from URL, when opening a webpage from within the webapp

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having a  encountered a problem launching a URL from within my flash application (built with Flash Builder 4.6).  It appears that Flash is stripping parameters from a new window's URL, just after the first URL parameter.

Here is an example of the Flash code, acting to when an image being clicked:

```
click="parentApplication.newWin(Application.application.parameters.myToolUrl)"
```

The parameter, myToolUrl, is read from the web apps WEB-INF/web.xml, where it is defined as:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>myToolUrl</param-name>
    <param-value><![CDATA[https://rest.mysite.com/rest/namespace/CustomerCollateral/mytool.zip?uid=3f50b19db5a446b985905a437938f6bc/A5548693149881f33548&expires=1472722653&signature=ovpanUxcrIDzcaKMjDr%2FGqJQ2DQ%3D]]></param-value>
</context-param>
```

As you can see, I have tried wrapping the URL in CDATA blocks, trying to get Flash to leave the parameters alone, but that is not helping.

The behavior is when I click on the link, in the flash application, a new window is opened, with the URL below:

```
https://rest.mysite.com/rest/namespace/CustomerCollateral/mytool.zip?uid=3f50b19db5a446b985905a437938f6bc/A5548693149881f33548
```

If I enter the whole URL, from the web.xml file, the zip file is opened normally.

```
https://rest.mysite.com/rest/namespace/CustomerCollateral/mytool.zip?uid=3f50b19db5a446b985905a437938f6bc/A5548693149881f33548&expires=1472722653&signature=ovpanUxcrIDzcaKMjDr%2FGqJQ2DQ%3D
```

Is there something special with an "expires" tag in Flash?  is & the right way to append a list of attributes?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should the code that you're using in your `newWin()` method. There is nothing special about having an "expires" parameter in your query string. You should check that the URL is being extracted properly from the `parameters` object (ie: verify the URL is correct inside your `newWin()` method).

Comment: Thanks, still  working the problem, but I did not realize newWin() was one of our own library functions.  I thought it was something actionscript provided.